# Rails 3 path matching without any route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

The following line is the only line un-commented in the `routes.rb`

```
root :to => "newbooks#index"
```

However any random url with "recent" at the end goes to `/newbooks/index`.

For e.g. if I type `localhost:3000/xywasdasas/asdas/recent` it goes to `/newbooks/index`. If I don't include `recent` at the end it gives the "no route found" error. Also putting a parameter in the url like `localhost:3000/xywasdasas/asdas/recent?q=abc` also gives an routing error.

My application is Rails 3. Totally baffled with this, why does it route to newbooks/index when `recent` is present at the end with only the single line in `routes.rb`???

Adding output from rake routes:

```
root  /(.:format) {:controller=>"newbooks", :action=>"index"}
page  /pages/*id  {:controller=>"high_voltage/pages", :action=>"show"}
```

the high voltage route is not in my routes file or controllers folder. Not sure where it is coming from.

Comment: Could you post the output from running `rake routes` on the application?

Comment: It could be coming from a gem - are you adding any extra gems to your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a rack rewrite gem config that was redirecting any url with 6 letter word at the end to the root path.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Probe  'rake routes' for get all the routes avaibles...

Look if you write an